# Link aggregation: disable spanning tree

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, packet-tracer, etherchannel

It's a simple question, with switch interfaces using etherchannel,is necessary to use `bpduguard` in these interfaces for that disable Spanning-tree? Because using mode simulation of Packet Tracer, I can see STP Packet coming and going between the links.

Comment: That's NOT what `bpduguard` does. BPDU Guard ***shuts down*** ports where *any* BPDU is seen. BPDU Guard is a mechanism to secure your spanning-tree infrastructure (since there's no security in the protocol itself.)

Comment: Off course, disabling BPDU, guarantee that ports don't join to the spanning-tree algorithm, correct?

Comment: Depends on the switch. Disabling STP does not necessary also *block* STP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etherchannel has a way of fooling STP into thinking all the interfaces in a bundle are a single interface, and the etherchannel handles the STP, so you don't want to disable, or mess with, STP on etherchannels since it takes care of STP for you, and you risk creating loops if you change STP on an etherchannel. It is the same thing for an etherchannel bundle as it would be for any interface connecting to another switch: disabling STP can have very bad consequences.